# Array.filter numbers plus zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, numbers

I have an easy problem but i'm stuck with it: I would like to transform a list of integers and strings and returns a new list with the strings filtered out :

exemple : `([99,5,'love','hate']) == [99,5]`

I used `.filter` but the zero are filtered as well. What would be the best option?

```js
function filter(l) {
  var arr = l.filter(Number);
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: .maybe typeof() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` with your own function:

```
function filter(l) {
  var arr = l.filter(function(n) {
    return typeof n === "number";
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Note that when you use the Number constructor, you'll include numbers and also any value that can successfully be converted to a number. Including such things is a little tricky, since the Number constructor *always* returns a number. The value might be `NaN`, but as it happens `NaN` is in fact a number, despite its intrinsic insistence that it isn't.

Comment: @Tushar ?? This will not exclude zero, because `typeof 0` is `"number"`.

Comment: @Tushar note that the OP explicitly does *not* want to exclude zero.

Comment: Oh, I thought he wants to exclude zero

Comment: I know the question is not about shortening/optimizing code, but code can be shortened by returning the result of filter  `return l.filter(function(n) {
    return typeof n === "number";
  });`

Answer (score 2):

Try these helper functions along with [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you want to strictly filter out only integers:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function isInt(n) {
  return isNumber(n) && n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Try these on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/r9y0yg4u/)

```js
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function isInt(n) {
  return isNumber(n) && n % 1 === 0;
}

var array = [99,5,'love','hate'];

var result = array.filter(function(x) {
  return isInt(x);
});

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
Array: [99,5,'love','hate']
<br/>Result: <pre id="output"></pre>
```

**EDIT:** This has a side-effect of string-representation of integers also being returned - so  `[99,5,'love','hate', '23']` will return `[99, 5, '23']` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Careful - `parseFloat()` returns the number `23` for the string `"23skidoo"`! This also allows strings that look like valid numbers, and that may or may not be what the OP wants (it's unclear).

Comment: Agreed. Which is why the `isNumber` function checks for `isFinite` as well. But one (probably undesired) side-effect of this solution is that a string that is an integer would also get into the returned list. I shall add it into the answer